# element onChange javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

```
<select name='cmg_select'  onChange="javascript:window.location.href='index.php?'+this.value">
    <option value='pening'> pening </option>
    <option value='complete'> complete </option>
    <option value='pening'> pening </option>
</select>
```

The concatenation is not working.

Comment: `onChange` can and should be written `onchange` .

Comment: And you shouldn't have two items with the same label and value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remove the `javascript:` portion
2. Remove the `href` portion

The result :

`< select name='cmg_select' onchange="window.location='index.php?'+this.value" >`

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead

```
<select name='cmg_select' onChange="window.location.href='index.php?'+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
<option value='pening' > pening </option>
<option value='complete' > complete </option>
<option value='pening' > pening </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `javascript:` from the `onchange` attribute.